# Should we merge Meteor and Meteorjs tags?

Tags: support, retag-request, reputation

I noticed recently that there are tags for [Meteor](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteor) and [Meteorjs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorjs) and it seems they refer to the same thing. Should we merge them? And if so, how is that done, and how many reputation points are required to do that?

Edit: I just saw this post on Meta Exchange: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) I wonder if tag synonyms would be the best first way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Good point, I support your idea to merge these two tags into a single `Meteor` tag. while there is only 5 posts tagged with `metereojs`. I think to do so we need mod privilege as described in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256229/merge-the-merge-tags-tool-with-the-synonymous-create-tag-synonym-tool).
[image]

Comment: Hello Badr, I am glad you agree :)  Do you know how many reputation points are required for merging?  I could not see that in the post you linked.  I also edited my question to ask if tagging the two tags as synonyms might be the best first step (see the link I added). That would definitely be within you reputation points range.

Comment: Oh, I now see the screen shot you posted suggests they are already tagged as synonyms.  Can you confirm that?  If so, maybe that's enough?  I did read somewhere that all good tag synonyms should eventually be merged.

Comment: I think they aren't synonym pls check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Yep, agree with you both :-)